# If $f$ is a Sobolev $H^1$-function and vanishes everywhere except for a point, is it constantly zero?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ be the usual $L^2$-based Sobolev space. If $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ satisfies $f=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$, can one conclude that $f=0$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

I think this is true because the condition implies $f$ can only be supported at $\{0\}$, so it must be a linear combination of derivatives of the delta distribution at $\{0\}$, but none of these distributions are in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Is this argument correct?

Comment: $H^1$ is a space of locally integrable functions, thus as an element of $H^1$, $f$ is defined by its value almost everywhere. To make what you said about $\delta,\delta'$ rigorous, you need to look at sequences of functions $\in H^1$ (or $C^\infty_c$) converging to $\delta,\delta'$ in the sense of distributions, and show they don't converge in $H^1$.

Comment: Functions in $H^1$ are identified up to sets of measure zero. So your function is the same (i.e., in the same equivalence class) as the identically zero function in $H^1$.